# Proving that set $Z = \{(x,y) : F (x, y) = 0\}$ has measure $0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

Question:  Prove that if $F$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$, such that for each $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$,
the equation $F(x_0, y) = 0$ has a countable number of solutions y, then $Z = \{(x,y) : F (x, y) = 0\}$ has measure $0$.

Solution attempt: we can write $Z$ as $\cup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\{(x,y): F (x, y) = 0\}$ and each such subset is now countable by hypothesis. I am trying to write this as the the countable union of countable sets, then the result follows since we can bound the measure with a zero series. But how to write $Z$ as the countable union of countable sets? Suggestions?

Comment: I'd use Fubini-Tonelli on the indicator function of $Z$.

Comment: The problem is that $Z$ cannot always be written as a countable union of countable sets, for then $Z$ itself would be countable, which is not the case always (For example , $F(x_0,y) = y^2$ has uncountable zero set $\mathbb R \times\{0\}$, although each slice of the zero set has only one point $(x_0,0)$). You need to use the definition of the product measure of $Z$ : you know what the "slices" of $Z$ are. So Fubini theorem will apply.

Comment: Ahh thanks it is clear now.

Comment: @olgaolgano you should post your own solution, then accept it. That way, you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z$ is measurable as $Z=F^{-1}\{0\}$ and $F$ is measurable. This implies that $\chi_Z$ is measurable. 
Now by Fubini-Tonelli Theorem we can write:
$m(Z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_Z dm=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{Z'} dy)dx=
\int_{\mathbb{R}}m(Z')dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}0=0$, where $Z'$ is $Z$ but for a fixed $x_0$.